# Find the derivative of $y=\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}$$

$$\frac{(1+\tan x)(\sec^2x)-(\tan x)(\sec^2x)}{(1+\tan x)^2}$$

I understand this first step but I struggle with simplifying to end up with only $$\sec^2x$$ in the numerator.

Comment: Try the distributive property, expanding the term on the left.

Comment: Just expand: $(1+\tan x)(\sec^2 x) = \sec^2 x + \tan x\sec^2 x$, and similarly for the other term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1+\tan x)(\sec^2 x) - \tan x \sec^2 x = (1 + \tan x - \tan x)\sec^2 x = \sec^2 x$

Just factor the $\sec^2 x$ out of the top.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating $\tfrac{u}{1+u}=1-\tfrac{1}{1+u}$ gives $\tfrac{u'}{\left(1+u\right)^2}$, which for $u=\tan x$ gives $$\frac{\sec^2 x}{\left(1+\tan x\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ (rewrite as much or as little as you like).

Answer (score 1):

so you have

$$\frac{(1+\tan x)(\sec^2x)-(\tan x)(\sec^2x)}{(1+\tan x)^2}$$

so

$$(1+\tan x)(\sec^2x)-(\tan x)(sec^2x) = \sec^2x + \tan x sec^2x - \tan x sec^2x$$

as the $\tan x sec^2x$ terms cancel each other out so this just

$$= \sec^2x$$